# Does arduino count++ has a limit and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, count, arduino, counter, limit

I needed to make a meters counter for a work thing, so I decided to just Arduino for it. I found an old encoder, found/wrote a simple code and hacked it all together and encountered a unexpected problem.

For some reason my counter won't count past around 8 meters or 31991 encoder pulses. Once it reaches this 8m limit, the number turns negative and starts counting backwards like -7.9 >  -7.8 (i.e. continues counting upward towards 0).
Then it reaches zero and again counts to 8...

This is very strange to me and my limited coding knowledge can't fix it.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what I could do to make it work?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define inputA_in 6
#define inputB_in 7

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int inputA_V = 0;
int inputB_V = 0;
int inputA = 0;
int inputB = 0;
int counter = 0;
// smeni vrednost tuka pred run 
int console_frequency_milliseconds = 200; /// edna sekunda


int aLastState = 0;
int bLastState = 0;
float meters = 0.0;
unsigned long lasttime = 0;

int move_positive = 0;
int move_negative = 0; 

  int maximum_input_digital_v = 300;   //treba da citash od konzola i da gi setirash max i min
  int minimum_input_digital_v = 0;
  int logical_threshold_v = 150;       //brojkive se random staveni

void setup() {

  pinMode (inputA_in, INPUT);
  pinMode (inputB_in, INPUT);

  Serial.begin (9600);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD
  lcd.print("Metraza [m]");

  aLastState = inputA;
  bLastState = inputB;
  lasttime = 0;
}

void loop () {

  inputA = digitalRead(inputA_in);

  if (inputA != aLastState) {
    if (digitalRead(inputB_in) != inputA) {
      counter ++;
      aLastState = inputA;
    } else {
      counter --;
       aLastState = inputA;
    }
  }
   if (millis() - console_frequency_milliseconds > lasttime)//Detect once every 150ms
  {
    meters = 0.50014 * counter / 2000;
    Serial.print("Position: ");
    Serial.println(meters);
       lasttime = millis();

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  //Print a message to second line of LCD
  lcd.print(meters);
  }

}
```

Comment: Read the fine manual https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow miloshIra. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

Your counter is a simple `int`,

```
int counter = 0;
```

It seems that on your system they are only 16bit wide (with a maximum value of 32767), not surprising.
Use

```
long int counter = 0;
```

to get wider variables.

You might also want to change the calculation from

```
meters = 0.50014 * counter / 2000;
```

to

```
meters = 0.50014 * counter / 2000.0;
```

to avoid losing precision and range. Even with an int that would extend your range from 31991 encoder pulses to 32757 encoder pulses; and analog for the wider range.

You might also like to try changing the `counter` to an `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`. I did not analyse your whole code, but I think you do not have anything which relies on representation of negative numbers. So you probably could double the range again. But no guarantees, subject to testing.

Comment: Thank you guys, you never fail to make me look stupid :) i checked the theory behind long int and it will do the job for me since i only need to measure up to around 2000m, Thank again.

Comment: Hello @miloshIra. I see you have been in and have not responded to my proposal to clarify what is missing for you to consider this answer helpful. If it is not what you are looking for, then you really need to explain why, because (at the risk of seeming vain), it does not seem like you will get another and different answer. So if you are waiting for something, please let me know.